# SelectionMode.MULTIPLE with TAB to navigate to next cell

Tags: javafx

I'm currently using TAB to navigate to next cell. `selectNext()` or `selectRightCell()` works fine when I'm using `SelectionMode.SINGLE`.

However, when using `SelectionMode.MULTIPLE`, its selecting multiple cells as I TAB.

I'm using a TableView. I need `SelectionMode.MULTIPLE` for the copy & paste function.

Is there a way to make it work in `SelectionMode.MULTIPLE`?

```
    fixedTable.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            switch (event.getCode()){
                case TAB:
                    if (event.isShiftDown()) {
                        fixedTable.getSelectionModel().selectPrevious();                      
                    } else {
                        fixedTable.getSelectionModel().selectNext();
                    }
                    event.consume();
                    break;

                case ENTER:
                    return;

                case C:
                    if(event.isControlDown()){
                        copySelectionToClipboard(fixedTable) ;
                    }
                    event.consume();
                    break;

                case V:
                    if(event.isControlDown()){
                        pasteFromClipboard(fixedTable);
                    }
                    event.consume();
                    break;

                default:
                    if (fixedTable.getEditingCell() == null) {
                        if (event.getCode().isLetterKey() || event.getCode().isDigitKey()) {
                            TablePosition focusedCellPosition = fixedTable.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
                            fixedTable.edit(focusedCellPosition.getRow(), focusedCellPosition.getTableColumn());
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It would help us a lot if you are able to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You didn't specify the control you are using, a TreeView? ListView? TableView?.

Comment: as @JKostikiadis already noted in her answer, selectNext/Previous (or any other of the selectXX methods) work by adding to the selection in multiple mode - that's specified in the api doc (hint, hint: please read it ;) so it's working, no bug. If you need a different behavior you have to implement it yourself - by clear/reselect as in the answer or by changing the selection mode around the tabbing code (didn't try, might implicitly clear the selection) or by implementing a custom selectionModel with additional api (not easy, everything's package private)

Comment: @kleopatra, I was thinking if there's any easy workaround with the methods provided. I've also tried changing the selection mode but it don't work properly like what you said. Anyway, thanks again for the explanation, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to handle the selection on your own. The reason is because the methods `selectPrevious()` and `selectNext()` tries to select the previous ( or the next ) without removing the current selected row ( when you set the selection mode to be `SelectionMode.MULTIPLE`) , also you can't use them and just remove the previous selecting by just calling `clearSelection()` because this will set the selected index to -1 and then the methods `selectPrevious()` and `selectNext()` will select the last or the first row only.

Here is how you could implement the selection on your own :

```
// the rest of your switch statement
...
case TAB:
    // Find the current selected row
    int currentSelection = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    // remove the previous selection
    table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    if (event.isShiftDown()) {
        currentSelection--;
    } else {
        currentSelection++;
    }

    // find the size of our table
    int size = table.getItems().size() - 1;

    // we was on the first element and we try to go back
    if(currentSelection < 0){
        // either do nothing or select the last entry
        table.getSelectionModel().select(size);
    }else if(currentSelection > size) {
        // we are at the last index, do nothing or go to 0
        table.getSelectionModel().select(0);
    }else {
        // we are between (0,size) 
        table.getSelectionModel().select(currentSelection);
    }
    event.consume();
    break;
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation! Appreciate it :)